# Reducing the textbox width with HTML?

Tags: html, css

Basic HTML Question:  My text input field stretches across the entire webpage and I want to center it and make it look a bit more friendly.

I'm in Wordpress and am editing the HTML.  Here is what I currently have:

```
<input name="FNAME" required="" type="text" placeholder="First Name" maxlength="5"/></p>
```

Is there a difference if I use maxlength=, maxlength:, maxlength:50px etc?

I know this is basic, but i've been playing around with this for a while now.

Thanks so much!

Comment: thats a question for your css.

Comment: Sorry, I meant, maxwidth.  When I add the maxwith it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

`maxlength` is an HTML input attribute which determines the maximum number of characters which can be entered into the input. `maxlength=50` means that the user can't enter more than 50 characters.

What you want is CSS, which controls styling. The following would make the input 50% width of its containing element and center it within that element.

```
input {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

`max-width` sets the maximum width that an element can ever be. It overrides `width`. It's especially useful in setting up responsive designs. In general though, if you merely want to set the width of an element, use `width`.

Comment: got it.  Yes, I want to just change the width of the element.  Here is what I currently have, but it's still not changing:  <input type="text" width="50" name="FNAME" placeholder="First Name" required>

Comment: `width` isn't a valid attribute on an text input so it's just being ignored. to add inline styles, you need to use the `style` attribute. `<input type="text" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto; width:50%;" name="FNAME" placeholder="First Name" required>` is the equivalent of the CSS in my answer.

Comment: Ryan, thank you so much!!  Apologies for such a simple question, but I really do appreciate it.  This worked for me!